# Searching a string with multiple double values for one certain double value?

Tags: java, string, search, double, substring

I have to create a calculator for my Computer Science class. I can calculate double values if they are only numbers like 3.4 or 6.8, while other double values like 64.7 or 6.78 will not work due to how I searched the String for the doubles. I am wondering if there is any way to find the doubles in the string or not. P.S. I know that testing the operator can be done a lot easier with switches. I am working on it.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Declares my input variables and Scanner variable
    String firstInput;
    String secondInput;
    String userProblem;
    char operator;
    //Creates the scanner
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Asks for input
    System.out.println("Please enter a problem you would like to calculate (ex. \"2.0 * 4.3\")");
    userProblem = userInput.nextLine();

    //Finds the doubles in the string and the operator
    firstInput = userProblem.substring(0, 3);
    secondInput = userProblem.substring(6, 9);
    operator = userProblem.charAt(4);

    //parses the strings to doubles
    double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstInput);
    double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondInput);

    //Tests for the operator and executes accordingly
    if(operator == '+'){
        System.out.println(firstNumber + secondNumber);
    }
    else{
        if(operator == '-'){
            System.out.println(firstNumber - secondNumber);
        }
        else{
            if(operator == '*'){
                System.out.println(firstNumber * secondNumber);
            }
            else{
                if(operator == '/'){
                    System.out.println(firstNumber / secondNumber);
                }
                else{
                    if(operator == '%'){
                        System.out.println(firstNumber % secondNumber);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("You did not input correctly");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please share the expected user input.

Comment: Hint: a substring consisting only of digits and `.` is a candidate for a number.

Comment: What I'm looking for people to input is  "6.5 * 3.2" exactly like that. One whole number, with a single decimal placement, then a space, then another whole number with a single decimal

Comment: What you said in your question was that you were looking for numbers with more digits.  "6.57 * 4.38" instead of "6.5 * 3.2".  Henry gave you a good hint.

Comment: I think I can do this. Thank you markspace and Henry.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I think I will have to use regex patterns correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code snippet for extracting two inputs and operator as well.

```
String[] tokensVal = userProblem.split("[-+*/%]");
firstInput = tokensVal[0].trim();
secondInput = tokensVal[1].trim();
operator = userProblem.charAt(tokensVal[0].length());
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark it as correct. This will be useful for other viewers.